# Something missing in iPhone/PHP encryption/decryption

Tags: php, objective-c, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I have been trying to implement some encryption between an iPhone app and a PHP web service. It's not working however. It seems like the first half of the text is NOT decrypted while the second half is decrypted just fine. What should I do?

The PHP encryption method is as follows:

```
function decrypt($str, $iv) {
    $iv .= "00000000";
    $str = base64_decode($str);
    return self::decrypt_data($str, $iv, self::secret_key);
}
```

The iPhone stuff that encrypts the text uses a CryptoHelper class like this:

```
NSString *encrypted = [[CryptoHelper sharedInstance] encryptString:dataString];
```

The CryptoHelper class can be seen at http://pastie.org/1267796.

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple example where you send a known Base64 encoded string from the iPhone app to PHP.

Compare the known valid string to what PHP is getting. I know recently, when trying to do an Ajax post from a script to PHP, we were having trouble with some characters (specifically `+`) being converted to spaces by PHP because it was doing a URL decode automatically. We had to switch all `+` to their `%` (URL-encoded `%2B`) equivalent. This fixed the problem for us.

Comment: @Mads Godvin Jensen, what I would suggest next would be to determine if the problem is with the cryptohelper doing the encoding or the transmission after encoded. Use php to `base64_encode` your string and try sending that as a simple string, decode it and see if there are any errors (url_encode to make sure that isn't a problem also). If that works without a problem then use the CryptoHelper to encrypt the same string and display the results to screen then compare visually each character to see if something is not the same. The problem should be fairly easy to spot.